# JavaScript replace characters with for loop

Tags: javascript

This is a simple program to replace the characters of a string with another using for loop and if statements.
However, I was not getting the desired result I want to get.
Here is the code:

```js
var str1 = "Optimism is the key to victory"

var str2 = ""

for(let i=0; i<str1.length;i++){
  if(str1[i] == "i"){
    var temp = str1[i]
    temp = "1"
    str2 += temp
  }
  if(str1[i] == "e"){
    var temp2 = str1[i]
    temp2 = "3"
    str2 += temp2
  }
  else{
    str2 += str1[i]
    }
 }
console.log(str2)
```

The result is this:
"Opt1im1ism 1is th3 k3y to v1ictory"
Why does it add another 'i' after '1' and how do I remove it?
(thanks for the response in advance!)

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
if (...) {
  ...
}
if (...) {
  ...
}
else {
  ...
}
```

The first `if` is not chained with the later two blocks - whenever the first condition is fulfilled, one of the other conditions will necessarily be fulfilled as well, resulting in `str2` being concatenated to twice in a single iteration instead of once.

Use `else`/`if` instead.

```js
var str1 = "Optimism is the key to victory"

var str2 = ""

for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
  if (str1[i] == "i") {
    var temp = str1[i]
    temp = "1"
    str2 += temp
  } else if (str1[i] == "e") {
    var temp2 = str1[i]
    temp2 = "3"
    str2 += temp2
  } else {
    str2 += str1[i]
  }
}
console.log(str2)
```

More elegantly:

```js
var str1 = "Optimism is the key to victory"

var str2 = ""

for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
  if (str1[i] == "i") {
    str2 += "1"
  } else if (str1[i] == "e") {
    str2 += "3"
  } else {
    str2 += str1[i]
  }
}
console.log(str2)
```

Or ditch the indicies, they aren't helping much:

```js
var str1 = "Optimism is the key to victory"

var str2 = ""

for (const char of str1) {
  if (char == "i") {
    str2 += "1"
  } else if (char == "e") {
    str2 += "3"
  } else {
    str2 += char
  }
}
console.log(str2)
```

Or even

```js
const str1 = "Optimism is the key to victory"
const str2 = str1.replace(/[ie]/g, char => char === 'i' ? '1' : '3');
console.log(str2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't considered the else if part.

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

What your code does is create two separate **if else blocks**.

First if checks for `i` .
Second if-else checks for `e` or not `e`.
Now the character `i` satisfies the first if condition and second else condition. That is why the code in both blocks get executed when the character `i` is encountered.

Use `else if`

```js
var str1 = "Optimism is the key to victory"

var str2 = ""

for(let i=0; i<str1.length;i++){
  if(str1[i] == "i"){
    var temp = str1[i]
    temp = "1"
    str2 += temp
  }
  else if(str1[i] == "e"){
    var temp2 = str1[i]
    temp2 = "3"
    str2 += temp2
  }
  else{
    str2 += str1[i]
    }
 }
console.log(str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the result first [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string, and then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the string array to replace it with a replacement string using `dict` and finally [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#:%7E:text=prototype.-,join(),returned%20without%20using%20the%20separator.) the string to get the final result.

```js
var str1 = "Optimism is the key to victory";
const dict = {
  i: 1,
  e: 3,
};
const result = str1
  .split("")
  .map((c) => (dict[c] ? dict[c] : c))
  .join("");

console.log(result);
```